# How to fix Hair strand - texture

Tags: hair

[image]

[image]

Working on the retopology of this mesh I lost the info about the hair. If you notice the strands in picture 1 looks non linear and picture 2 look linear. I don't know if blender updated and change this or  I just don't remember where to change it. ... I think the issue was in cycles hair rendering-> primitive-> line segment / Curve Segment but I don't find it anymore in the new update. how can I do then to get a more defined strand?Can somebody help me? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The dolls looks scary - the hair system has been updated lately .. how old was your model?

Comment: Yes. This is why I am working on retopology of the doll. I think the issue was in cycles hair rendering-> primitive-> line segment but I don't find it anymore in the new update. how can I do then to get a more defined strand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image][image]

After experimenting around I found a solution for this problem. Cycles Hair settings is not in the last blender update but the texture of the hair from linear to curve can be improved just by changing steps from 2 (settings default in the hair properties) to 6.[image]